Reeb graphs with different numbers of connected components have infinite interleaving distance
Let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ two levelset tame functions. Let $R_f$ and $R_g$ be two Reeb graphs with different numbers of connected components. I want to show that their interleaving distance satisfies $d_I(R_f,R_g)=\infty$.
I thought of doing a proof via contraposition, i.e. showing that if $d_I(R_f,R_g)<\infty$, then the two Reeb graphs must have the same number of connected components. $d_I(R_f,R_g)<\infty$ means that there is a $d$ such that $R_f$ and $R_g$ are $d$-interleaved, so we ge commutative diagrams for the interleaving. My idea was applying $0^{th}$ homology to the diagram and to then use that the inclusion induce isomorphisms, so there must be a surjection between $H_0(R_f)$ and $H_0(S_d(R_g))$, and an injection between $H_0(S_d(R_g))$ and $H_0(S_{2d}(R_f))$ where we denote by $S_d(R_g)$ the $d$-smoothing of $R_g$. Does this approach make sense?
Thanks in advance!

That argument may be a bit over-convoluted. You can just use that the three spaces on the top of the diagram, that is $R_f$, $S_{\epsilon}(R_f)$ and $S_{2 \epsilon}(R_f)$, have the same number of connected components (this should be relatively easy to check).  The same happens for the spaces on the bottom of the diagram: $R_g$, $S_{\epsilon}(R_g)$ and $S_{2 \epsilon}(R_g)$ have the same number of cc. Then if the number of cc is not the same in the top and bottom parts either the diagram does not commute or the functions in the arrows are not maps. This should be enough to convince Patrick.
